# Error on GridView postback

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have two sites in a web application. What I want to do is update the list from Site A from a web part in Site B using a button.

The problem is that if I don't use `Page.IsPostBack`, the page throws an unhandled exception when the button is clicked, BUT, the list in Site A is updated. But if I use `Page.IsPostBack`, I don't get the exception but the process doesn't push through; as a matter of fact, it doesn't even proceed to the eventhandler when the button is clicked.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = @"Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy><Query>";
                    query.ViewAttributes = "<FieldRef Name='Title' />";
                    query.ViewFields = string.Concat(
                        "<FieldRef Name='Title' />",
                        "<FieldRef Name='Status' />",
                        "<FieldRef Name='Severity' />",
                        "<FieldRef Name='Comment' />");

                    query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                    showGrid = new GridView();

                    this.Controls.Add(showGrid);

                    SPList list = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists["Ticket List"];
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();                    

                    ButtonField approveBtn = new ButtonField();
                    approveBtn.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
                    approveBtn.CommandName = "Update";


                    approveBtn.Text = "Approve";
                    showGrid.Columns.Add(approveBtn);

                    dt = list.Items.GetDataTable().Copy();
                    dt = list.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
                    showGrid.DataSource = dt;

                    showGrid.DataBind();

                    showGrid.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(inventoryGridView_RowCommand);
                }
            }
```

Eventhandler

```
if (e.CommandName == "Update")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = showGrid.Rows[index];
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb Web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        // Open List 
                        SPList list = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists["Ticket List"];
                        SPListItem _listItem = list.Items[row.RowIndex];
                        _listItem["Status"] = "Approved";
                        _listItem.Update();
                        Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Page Load event you are creating the Grid and add it to Controls collection. So when you are not going for Postback....it will again create the control but will when u try to add it will throw exception.

Check it out by debugging the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Would you please elaborate? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Have you debug your solution ? Where have u assigned the ID for the Grid.

Comment: Okay...U created one control with some id in pageload once and if u don't put a check for ISPostback...it will again try to create the same control with same id and adding it to control collection. Which will throw error as the id's of the controls must always be unique.